# Altium: Pouring Polygon attached to a specific net class for direct connections

Tags: altium

I've got multiple polygons on this board I'm laying out. Some want to have direct connetsions to pads and others not.

I was originally adding lots of nets to my rules to allow for direct connections and thought there must be a better way. I originally tried wildcards in the names of the nets in the rules, but that didn't work.

I then had the idea that I could create a netclass called Solid Pour and assign the nets I wanted to have solid connections, to this net class. I did this by right clicking on  the net and assigning it to the relevant net class.

In the polygon rules I then  created a rule called Solid By Class, put that as highest priority and said when the first object matches Net Class of Solid Pour, the connect style should be direct connect. However, this doesn't work, I still have to go in and add the specific net name to a custom query. I'm going to end up with a custom query a million kilometers long at this rate!

Is there are way to do what I want to do please? Or am I doing essentially the right thing, but missing an important step out? I can see the nets are being assigned to the relevant class.

Comment: How many nets and how many polygons need special treatment?

Comment: And, just to be sure, did you "repour all" after your rule changes?

Comment: I have twelve rooms each of which has three polygons that need direct assignment. There are then four polygons in each room that want relef. Then there's the ground plane for  the whole board which will want relief. 

And yes, I remembered to repour the polys. I'm not quite *that* stupid. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, had to ask. We get questions from people with all experience levels.

Comment: I know, I wasn't in the slightest bit offended. :) and, to be fair, I'm probably doing something incredibly stupid!

Comment: One more question, do you have overlapping polygons?  I've had trouble before where the relief/direct rules don't work as expected when polygons overlap.

Comment: Not in the case. I have also had fun and games in the past where I've had polygons within polygfons!

Comment: In case you don't get a useful answer, one practical solution might be to place fill regions around the pads you want direct-connected, and use the layout replication to copy them across rooms.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do this. You have to attach the net to to net class in the schematic and then take it though to the PCB. I did find tutorials on how to do this, but they were old and things have chnaged in v19 and above (maybe earlier).

So:

Place | Directive | Paramater Set

Attach that to the net.

Go into the properties of this placed Parameter Set, name it something sensible, then under classes click add and name the class to whatever you want. In my case, Solid Pour. You can copy and paste this to any other nets that you want pouring in a solid plane. For these repeated channels it makes them all part of the same class, which is great.

Then, update the PCB and add a Rule (Design | Rule) in the Plane Section, under Polygon Connect Style and you can simply say when the first object matches NetClass and the new net class will be in the drop down box.

It works exactly as I'd expected it to work then.

Obv, really...